# JavaScript TypeError - no method error

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am getting a TypeError by calling this code:

```
player = new Player({name:''});

Player = MeteorModel.extend({

  schema:{
    name:{type:String,},
    value:{}
  },

  belongsTo:{
    meteorCollection:'',  //which collection to add to
    methodName: ''   //which method to save on server side
  },

  print: function(){
    console.log(this);
  },

  create: function(prototype){

    this.fields.name = prototype.name;
    this.type = prototype.type;

    return this;
  },
  validate: function(){
    return true;
  }
});


var MeteorModel = function(){

    this.extend = function(prototype){

    this.model = prototype;
    return this;

  }

};
```

What should I make of this JavaScript TypeError:

```
TypeError: Object function(){

     this.extend = function(prototype){

     this.model = prototype;
     return this;

  }

 }
  has no method 'extend'
```

it has a function named extend right there? What's wrong?

the way I solved it:

I changed my code to this

```
var MeteorModelFunction = function(){

    this.extend = function(prototype){

    this.model = prototype;
    return this;

  }

};

MeteorModel = new MeteorModelFunction();
```

So I used the new keyword, as suggested. Frankly, this seems a little stupid, because I called new with "new Player()", but it works. Also, thanks JS for interlacing the terms "methods" with "functions".

Comment: And how are you calling that function ?

Comment: Could you show us your code not interlaced with your error message, along with how you called the method?

Comment: I updated the question. It's confusing and I can't really make it more clear. Legit problem though, so I appreciate the downvotes and votes to close, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it has a function named extend right there?

No, it doesn't. The object produced by this function if used as constructor would have:

```
var obj = new YourFunction();
obj.extend();
```

Usage of [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) keyword is important here.